# Can the direction of Contour Integral be affect to the result of integration?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, contour-integration, residue-calculus

Now i doing the home work about Residue Integration and i doubt that "Can the direction of Contour Integral be affect to the result of integration?" I mean with the same shape of contour but direction of contour changes from clockwise to counterclockwise or counterclockwise to clockwise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reversing the orientation flips the sign of the result. This follows more or less immediately from the formula to convert a contour integral to a normal integral.

One can define orientation for regions of other dimension as well, and you get the same effect.

Usually we assume all two-dimensional regions of the plane are positively oriented, thus the need for boundaries to go counter-clockwise. But if we specify the region to be negatively oriented, then integrals over it get their sign flipped, and its boundary must go clockwise. So this still fits in nicely with all of the nice theorems of contour integrals.

We can do this for points too. The 0-dimensional integral of $f$ over the point $x$ (oriented positively) is $f(x)$. With negative orientation, it is $-f(x)$. The fundamental theorem of calculus fits in nicely with the fact the boundary of a path from $a$ to $b$ consists of two points: the point $b$ oriented positively and the point $a$ oriented negatively.

Comment: For integration, i can understand that it can be affect to sign of result because boundary might change (e.g. "from infinity to -infinity" to "from -infinity to infinity") but for Residue Theorem there is only summation How can it affect?